# dividing tables into sub-tables

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var word=[
                [
                    "0. wordAng - wordPl 1. gap year -  rok przerwy po ukonczeniu szkoly sredniej 2. safety course -  kurs zasad bezpieczenstwa 3. increase -  zwiekszac sie (o ilosci/jakosci)4. decrease -  zmniejszac sie (o ilosci/jakosci) 5. within walking distance -  w odleglosci, ktora mozna pokonac pieszo 6. mention -  wspomniec o czyms 7. overland -  droga ladowa / naziemny 8. memorable -  niezapomniany/ godny zapamietania  9. sign up with -  zapisac sie/zaangazowac/zwiazac sie z  10. deliverer -  doreczyciel/dostawca 11. paragliding -  paralotnia 12. placement -  polozenie/lokalizacja 13. research -  badania naukowe 14. expences -  wydatki 15. cruise ship -  statek rejsowy 16. on board -  na pokladzie 17. off the coast -  z daleka od brzegu 18. available -  dostepne 19. working hours -  godziny pracy 20. deal with -  radzic sobie z 21. counsellor -  doradca/opiekun 22. freelance - pracowac jako wolny strzelec 23. call back -  oddzwonic pozniej 24. take on -  zatrudniac 25. hold a certificate -  posiadac dyplom 26. put through -  polaczyc przez telefon 27. flood -  powodz 28. volcanic eruption -  wybuch wulkanu 29. drought -  susza 30. pollution - zanieczyszczenie 31. earthquake -  trzesienie ziemi 32. pump out -  wypompowywac/emitowac 33. toward -  w kierunku 34. grow - rosnac/uprawiac 35. canoe -  kajak 36. fireworks -  fajerwerki 37. light up - rozswietlic 38. sheke - trzasc sie 39. fall off -  spadac/odpadac 40. twister -  tornado/traba powietrzna 41. calm -  spokojny/nieporuszony 42. weatherman -  prezenter pogody 43. strike -  uderzyc/nadejsc/dopasc 44. pray -  modlic sie 45. prayer -  modlitwa 46. put down -  wpisywac/klasc 47. huge -  ogromny/olbrzymi 48. directly - bezposrednio 49. unexpected -  nieoczekiwany 50. expected -  oczekiwany 51. chase -  gonic/scigac 52. awake -  obudzony/przebudzony/obudzic/przebudzic sie 53. prediction -  przewidywanie 54. predict -  przewidywac 55. spontaneous decision -  decyzja spontaniczna 56. global warming -  globalne ocieplenie 57. rising level -  podnoszacy sie poziom 58. cover -  przykrywac/pokrywac/przykrywa/pokrywa (czasownik i rzeczownik) 59. glacier -  lodowiec 60. well -  studnia 61. cause -  powodowac 62. precious -  drogocanny 63. collect donations -  zbierac datki 64. fossil fuel -  paliwo kopalne 65. ice cap -  pokrywa lodowa 66. blanket -  koc 67. shortage -  brak/niedobor 68. leak -  przeciekac/wyciek 69. dispose of -  unieszkodliwic/uporac sie z 70. dump -  sklad/zrzut 71. breed -  rasa/gatunek 72. die out -  wymrzec/wyginac 73. scarce -  rzadki/malo spotykany 74. look for -  szukac 75. look after -  opiekowac sie 76. cub -  kocie/mlode 77. cuddly -  milutki 78. fierce-looking -  wygladajacy groznie 79. habitat -  srodowisko/miejsce wystepowania 80. in case of -  w razie/jesli wystapi"
        ],
                [
                    "0. wordAng - wordPl 1. alidi - alidi 2. at gunpoint - pod grozba uzycia broni 3. beat sb up - pobic 4. burglar - wlamywacz 5. commit a crime - popelnic przestepstwo 6. criminal - przestepca 7. escape - uciekac 8. force - sila 9. forger - falszerz 10. get out of - wyjsc 11. getaway - ucieczka 12. hand over - przekazywac 13. hand sth in - wreczyc 14. hide - ukryc 15. hold up - napad rabunkowy 16. illegal - nielegalny 17. mugger - bandyta 18. mugging - kradzierz z rozbojem 19. murder - morderstwo 20. murderer - morderca 21. pickpocket - kieszonkowiec 22. prisoner - wiezien 23. ransom - okup 24. rob - rabowac 25. robber - zlodziej 26. robbery - napad  27. shoplifter - zlodziej sklepowy 28. shoplifting - kradzierz sklepowa 29. suspect - podejrzany 30. suspicious - podejrzany 31. suspiciously - podejrzliwie 32. theft - kradziez 33. thieft - zlodziej 34. threaten - grozic 35. tick off - dawac reprymende 36. violence - przemoc 37. appear - pojawiac sie 38. appearence - wygląd 39. author - autor 40. carry out duties - wypelniac obowiazki 41. clever diagnosis - inteligentan diagnoza 42. come out - ukazac sie 43. cuff - mankiet 44. carved pipe - rzezbiona fajka 45. deduce - wnioskowac 46. diary - dziennik 47. edition - wydanie 48. fictional - fikcyjny 49. immediate success - natychmiastowy sukces 50. indicate - wskazywac 51. insult - zniewazac 52. magnifying glass - szklo powiekszajace 53. notice - zauwazyc 54. observation - obserwacja 55. plot - fabula 56. relationships - kontakty 57. shopkeeper - kupiec 58. smooth patch - gładka lata 59. solve mysteries - rozwiazywac zagadki 60. tattoo - tatuaz 61. tradesman - handlowiec 62. trai - szkolic 63. who is behind it - kto za tym stoi 64. accuse sb of sth - oskarzyc kogos o cos 65. accused of - oskarzony o 66. arrest - aresztowac 67. cctv - kamera przemyslowa 68. avidence - dowody 69. fill in a form - wypelniac formularz 70. fingerprint - odcisk palca 71. forensic - sadowy 72. murder case - sprawa o morderstwo 73. proof - dowod 74. prosecute - oskarzac 75. punish - karac kogos 76. report - raport 77. scene of crime - miejsce przestepstwa 78. traces - slady 79. confess guilt - przyznawac sie do winy 80. court -sad 81. defendant - oskarzony 82. end up in jail - trafic do wiezienia 83. go on trial - miec proces 84. guilty - winny 85. innocent - niewinny 86. judge - sedzia 87. jury - lawa przysieglych 88. lawer - prawnik 89. make statements under oath - zeznawac pod przysiega 90. minor - drobny 91. pass sentence - wydawac wyrok 92. sentence sombady to - skazywac kogos na 93. try - sadzic 94. under oath - pod przysiega 95. victim - ofiara 96. witness - slabosc"
                ]
            ];
```

how can I divide this (1. gap year -  rok przerwy po ukonczeniu szkoly sredniej) array into substring like (gap year,rok przerwy po ukonczeniu szkoly sredniej)

I write this code but this code dividing like:

1: "wordPl , gap year"
2: " rok przerwy po ukonczeniu szkoly sredniej , safety course"

but i nead divivde like:
1: "gap year ,  rok przerwy po ukonczeniu szkoly sredniej"

```
    var splitedWord = [];
    var dividedWord = [];
    var dividedWord2 =[];
    var dividedWord3 =[];
    for(i=0;i<wordLength[chosenMonth];i++){
       splitedWord = word[chosenMonth][chosenMonth].split(".");
       divideWord = splitedWord.toString().replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
       dividedWord2 = divideWord.toString().split(" - ");
    }
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to split by number and then split by hyphen. For example,

```
word[0][0].split(/\s*\d+\.\s*/)[1].split(/ - /)
```

gives me

```
["wordAng", "wordPl"]
```

Comment: And taking all word translation pairs would be: `var allWords = word[0][0].split(/\s*\d+\.\s*/).filter(function (wordPairs) {return wordPairs.length>2}).map(function (wordPairs) {return wordPairs.split(/ - /)});`